# Mouse clicker able to repeat several clicks every n minutes

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, xdotool

I am on Linux Mint.

I need a mouse clicker able to repeat several mouse clicks every `n` minutes.

I have found one GUI solution from Murguu.com, but that link seems to be dead now.

The problem is it seems to be a trial version. And the full version costs a lot.

I am open to both GUI and CLI solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing the question, I was too inexperienced for a CLI solution.

Now the situation differs, and I actually use a shell script, that heavily uses `xdotool`, [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdotool.1.html).